# Загрузка файлов в ckeditor

Tags: django, ckeditor

Здравствуйте. Установил ckeditor 5.0.3. Когда в редакторе загружаю файл, он появляется в папке media/upload, но в редакторе не отображается. Просто битое изображение, а в коде путь указан верно.
Попробовал поставить file browser, прописал в конфиге ckeditor:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'filebrowser';
config.extraPlugins = 'popup';
```

Но не понимаю, использует этот плагин редактор или нет, так как до установки плагина никаких изменений.
В консоле браузера вижу сообщение: Статья с первичным ключом u'add/media/upload/2016/07/10/qtacdg.docx' не существует. 
Но по этому пути там файл лежит.
setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'ckeditor',
'ckeditor_uploader',
]

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     ('static', '/root/djangoenv/bin/blago/blago/static',)
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'upload/'
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL =     
'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
    'toolbar': 'None',
    },
}
```

Можете помочь? Спасибо!

Comment: u'add/media/upload/2016/07/10/qtacdg.docx' - это ж относительный путь. Где-то косяк в настройках базового пути до media

Comment: Ели сложить в папку файлы и через редактор открыть "файлы на сервере", то он показывает все файлы, что там лежат. Только битыми и не открывает. Пути получается верные?

Comment: Мне кажется вы ckeditor где-то неправильно настроили. Если media открывается, то проблема не в ней

Comment: @FeroxTL, приложил setting.py. Посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: предлагаю обсудить в чате http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42303/ckeditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Проверить настройки**

   Во-первых для media должен быть указан абсолютный путь. То есть он должен начинаться со `/` и никак иначе. В противном случае media будет ломиться в поддиректорию `media` текущей страницы, что неверно

   *Пример настройки статики и медиа*

   ```
   # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
   ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app1', 'static'),
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app2', 'filters', 'static'),
   ]
   ```
2. **Проверить настройки ckeditor**

   ```
   # ckeditor
   CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'  # тут как раз может быть относительный путь
   ```
3. **Проверить настройки статики и медиа**

   В современных версиях django это делается добавлением в главный файл `urls.py` следующего

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       # тут ваши urls
   ] + static(
       settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
   ) + static(
       settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
   )
   ```

Comment: К сожалению, из-за порога рейтинга не могу поставить бал. @FeroxTL, спасибо Вам за помощь